# PowerShell Copying only New added folders and email results

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-3.0, windows-server-2012

Is it possible to copy from the Source location only New folders that have been added.

I have a Source location that is updated with folders every 5 minutes. The PS1 script will run every 5 minutes and copy all the folders to the destination location.

The issue im having is - It's copying over everything, i only want it to match up what has already been copied over Prior and copy over only newly added folders, Instead of copying everything again that is already there. Is this possible?

Also if possible once the copying of only Recently added folders, can the script then email out completion of this with what is has done?

So far i have the following :

```
Copy-Item -Recurse \\192.168.1.37\d$\Transactions\* -Destination  D:\UK_Copy\Transactions_Bk -Force –Verbose
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a script that just loops. Something like:

```
$Source = "\\192.168.1.37\d$\Transactions\"
$Destination = "D:\UK_Copy\Transactions_Bk"
$LastScan = Get-ChildItem $Destination -recurse
While(1 -lt 2){
    $NewScan = Get-ChildItem $Source -recurse
    Compare-Object $NewScan -DifferenceObject $LastScan -Passthru | Copy-Item -Destination ($_.DirectoryName -replace [regex]::escape($source),$Destination) -force
    $LastScan = $NewScan
    Start-Sleep 300
}
```

That will get a listing of files in the destination, then look for files in the source that are new, or have changed compared to the destination and copy those over. Then it sets that scan as the last known listing to compare to, sleeps for 5 minutes, and loops again looking for files that are new or updated since the last scan.

Comment: Thanks for that. I have run the above but getting the following error                          Compare-Object : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Passthrough'.
At line:10 char:57
+     Compare-Object $NewScan -DifferenceObject $LastScan -Passthrough |
+                                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Compare-Object], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CompareObjectCommand

Comment: Sorry, was typing code not copying or anything. It's `-Passthru` (answer already updated) not `-Passthrough` as I had originally posted.